# Dust.js templates outputting &#65279;

Tags: html, dust.js

I have a dust template that is using a partial to render fields in a form:

```
{#Person}
{>"partial/field" field="FirstName" /}
{>"partial/field" field="MiddleName" /}
{>"partial/field" field="LastName" /}
{/Person}
```

This is resulting in HTML that looks mostly correct, except there's strange spacing in between each field's output.  When I inspect the markup using Chrome's developer tools, I see a mysterious HTML non-breaking space entity being output as ﻿ but I didn't put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that I had to change the encoding for the partial template file from UTF-8 to Codepage 1252.  Since I use Visual Studio, this was pretty easy: use `File > Advanced Save Options...`

It appears that entity ﻿ is used as the UTF byte order marker and was being output into the resulting HTML.  Hope this helps someone else struggling with this!

Comment: Finally, I found an answer for this, great job!